# Does there exist a $4$-dimensional contractible open manifold that is not homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^4$?

Tags: manifolds

This question might be answered on this platform already. However, I am lacking the expertise to make the connection myself.

I read about the [Mazur manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur_manifold) which are contractible manifolds with boundary which fail to be diffeomorphic (how about homeomorphic?) to $\mathbb R^4$. How about their interior?

I also read that some results of Freedman prove that there exist contractible 4-manifolds that are not homeomorphic to the 4-ball but I couldn't find the exact Proposition or Theorem yet.

Comment: Yes, interiors of Mazur manifolds are not homeomorphic to the Euclidean space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Verify that interiors of Mazur manifolds are not [simply-connected at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_at_infinity) unlike $R^4$. use the fact that the homology spheres bounding Mazur manifolds are not simply-connected.

Here are some details. Let's start with the definition of (topological) Mazur manifolds. Let $W$ be a compact contractible 4-dimensional manifold $W$ (necessarily with nonempty boundary $Y=\partial W$). A manifold $W$ is called a *topological Mazur manifold* if the boundary $Y$ is not simply-connected. Equivalently (this part is the 3-dimensional Poincare conjecture), $Y$ is not homeomorphic to the sphere $S^3$.

Here is a bit you can ignore if you do not know what homology means:

The above definition can be "reversed": Let $Y$ be a closed (compact and with empty boundary) 3-dimensional homology sphere, i.e. a connected nonempty orientable 3-dimensional manifold such that $H_1(Y)=0$. Then it is proven by Michael Freedman that for every manifold $Y$ with this property there exists a contractible compact 4-dimensional manifold $W$ (with boundary) such that $\partial W$ is homeomorphic to $Y$. Moreover, topology of $Y$ uniquely determines topology of $W$ (this is due to Richard Stong, Freedman's student).
Thus, whenever $Y$ is not simply-connected, the manifold $W$ is a topological Mazur manifold.

Now, you are saying:

> I read about the Mazur manifolds which are contractible manifolds with boundary which fail to be diffeomorphic (how about homeomorphic?) to ${\mathbb R}^4$.

This part is not quite right: Additionally, a Mazur manifold is required to be compact. Also,  the fact that such a manifold is not homeomorphic to $E^4={\mathbb R}^4$ is quite easy: A compact topological space cannot be homeomorphic to a noncompact one. Furthermore, a manifold with nonempty boundary cannot be homeomorphic to a manifold with empty boundary, such as ${\mathbb R}^4$.

I need one more definition:

Definition. A topological space $X$ is said to be *simply-connected at infinity* if the following two properties hold:

a. $X$ is 1-ended, meaning that for every compact $K\subset X$ there exists a compact $C\subset X$ whose interior contains $K$, such that any two points $x, y\notin C$ can be connected by a path in $X\setminus K$. (One can think of this property as "path-connected at infinity".)

b. For every compact $K\subset X$ there exists a compact $C\subset X$ whose interior contains $K$, such that every continuous map $f: S^1\to X\setminus C$ extends to a continuous map $F: D^2\to X\setminus K$.

Lemma 1. For each $n\ge 3$, the Euclidean space $E^n$ is simply-connected at infinity.

Proof. Each compact $K\subset E^n$ is contained in a round ball $B\subset E^n$. Take $C:= B$ for both parts (a) and (b) of the definition. Then $E^n\setminus B$ is homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}\times (0,\infty)$ (this is proven using spherical coordinates). Since $n\ge 2$, $S^{n-1}$ is simply-connected and, therefore, the product $S^{n-1}\times (0,\infty)$ is also simply-connected. hence, every map $S^1\to  E^n\setminus B$ extends to a map $D^2\to E^n\setminus B$. Lemma follows. qed

Lemma 2. Suppose that $W$ is a compact manifold with connected nonempty boundary $Y=\partial W$ and $Y$ is not simply-connected. Then the manifold $X:= W\setminus Y$ is not simply-connected at infinity.

Proof. It is known that the boundary of $W$ has *collar*, which is an open neighborhood $U$ of $Y$ in $W$ homeomorphic to $Y\times [0,1)$.

See also Proposition 3.42 in Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" for a self-contained proof.

In what follows, I will identity points of $U$ with their images in $Y\times [0,1)$.

Pick a homotopically-nontrivial loop $c_0: S^1\to Y$, i.e. one which does not extend to a map $D^2\to Y$. Then for every $t\in  (0,1)$, the loop
$$
c_t: S^1\to Y\times \{t\}\subset U, c_t(s)=(t, c_0(s))
$$
is homotopically nontrivial in $U$. (This is because  the inclusion map $Y\to U$ is a homotopy-equivalence.)

Now, take the compact $K:= W\setminus U$. For every compact $C\subset X=int(W)= W\setminus Y$, there exists $t\in (0,1)$ such that
$$
C\subset K\cup Y\times (t,1). 
$$
Therefore, there exists a loop $c_t$ as above, whose image is in $W\setminus C$ and such that $c_t$ is homotopically nontrivial in $U$. Hence, $X$ is not simply-connected at infinity.

Corollary. The interior of each topological Mazur manifold $W$ is not homeomorphic to $E^4$.

Proof. If  $X=int(W)$ is homeomorphic to $E^4$, then $X$ is simply-connected at infinity, contradicting Lemma 2. qed

Comment: Thanks for the hint. As a physicist I almost always work with open manifolds, rarely with manifolds with boundary and I have had almost no contact with algebraic topology. So at this point, I have little hope to go through the details of the proofs myself. Out of curiosity, what is the toolset employed in order to arrive at the result? And is there a standard/original reference I can point to? (I will employ this result in a physics text, in order to argue that there are contractible open 4-manifolds that do not admit a global holonomic frame.)

Comment: @LarsD.: I will then add details later on (I do not know a reference). A suggestion: When posting questions on MSE, it is useful to explain what is your level of familiarity with the subject. I did not expect anybody unfamiliar with algebraic topology to be aware of Mazur manifolds.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the central ideas should suffice. As long as I can follow some references from thereon, I will be super happy. :) Confirming my claim in first place already helped me a lot.

Comment: @LarsD. Incidentally: Do you know what the words "topological space", "homeomorphism" and "compact" precisely mean? I am just trying to gauge your level of familiarity with topology? In my experience, physicists frequently try to learn manifold topology without having any general topology background, which always spells trouble.

Comment: General topology is fine. I am sufficiently familiar with differential geometry, I took some of the mathematicians courses on smooth manifolds and fibre bundles in the smooth category. When it comes to algebraic topology, it becomes much more tricky. Though I visited very few lectures on algebraic topology for fun a few years back, my knowledge doesn't reach farther than a rough idea of what homology and cohomolgy are. I haven't acquired technical skills to work with them.
Btw, the manifolds we are talking about are assumed to be Hausdorff and paracompact/second countable, right?

Comment: @LarsD.: Right, these are the standard assumptions. Did you learn about homotopy-equivalences and the fundamental group? Homology theory is not needed for the proof.

Comment: Some homotopy is known. Enough to intuitively agree that contractibility is the same as homotopy-equivalence to a point.

Comment: Great answer, quite the level I needed. I will take a few moments to digest your answer and subsequently accept your answer. You are of course right that my statement about compact manifolds and manifolds with boundary was non-sense. I let myself be confused about open balls and closed balls. When I read about the 4-ball in the article on [Mazur manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur_manifold), I assumed it were meant the open ball. :D